# How to determine the namespace of a given attribute inside NodeChild

Tags: groovy, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse some Android XML using `XmlSlurper`. For a given child node, I want to detect whether or not an attribute with a particular namespace has been specified.

For example, in the following XML I would like to know whether the `EditText` node has had any attributes from the 'b' namespace declared:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:b="http://x.y.z.com">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        b:enabled="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I start by calling:

```
 def rootNode = new XmlSlurper().parseText(text)
```

to get a handle on the root `GPathResult`. As I iterate through the children, I am given an instance of `groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild`. On this class I can inspect the attributes by calling `attributes()` and in the case of `EditText` above, this will return the following map: `[layout_width: "fill_parent", layout_height: "wrap_content", enabled: "true"]`.

This is all well and good. However, there doesn't seem to be a way to query the namespace of a given attribute. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Node has a private variable attributeNamespaceMap. If you could access this then you'd be there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `XmlParser` rather than `XmlSlurper` and do this:

```
def xml = '''<LinearLayout
            |    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            |    xmlns:b="http://x.y.z.com">
            |
            |  <EditText
            |      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            |      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            |      b:enabled="true" />
            |</LinearLayout>'''.stripMargin()

def root = new XmlParser().parseText( xml )

root.EditText*.attributes()*.each { k, v ->
  println "$k.localPart $k.prefix($k.namespaceURI) = $v"
}
```

Which prints out

```
layout_width android(http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android) = fill_parent
layout_height android(http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android) = wrap_content
enabled b(http://x.y.z.com) = true
```

---

#### Edit

To use XmlSlurper, you first need to access the `namespaceTagHints` property from the root node using reflection:

```
def rootNode = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)

def xmlClass = rootNode.getClass()
def gpathClass = xmlClass.getSuperclass()
def namespaceTagHintsField = gpathClass.getDeclaredField("namespaceTagHints")
namespaceTagHintsField.setAccessible(true)

def namespaceDeclarations = namespaceTagHintsField.get(rootNode)
```

`namespaceTagHints` is a property of [GPathResult](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/1.7.2/groovy/util/slurpersupport/GPathResult.java), which is a superclass of `NodeChild`.

You can then cross-reference this map to access the namespace prefix and print out the same result as above:

```
rootNode.EditText.nodeIterator().each { groovy.util.slurpersupport.Node n ->
  n.@attributeNamespaces.each { name, ns ->
    def prefix = namespaceDeclarations.find {key, value -> value == ns}.key
    println "$name $prefix($ns) = ${n.attributes()"$name"}"
  }
}
```

Comment: Useful answer, thanks, but for performance reasons I want to use XmlSlurper in my case.

Comment: You can access the namespace prefix by accessing the `namespaceTagHints` in `GPathResult`. I found that solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385303/groovy-xml-parsing-with-namespaces-which-are-changing-everytime. I've updated your answer accordingly.

Comment: Although this solution seems harder than it ought to be, I'm marking this as accepted. I still feel [NodeChild](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/maven2/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/1.5.4/groovy/util/slurpersupport/NodeChild.java) ought to expose an `attributeNamespaces()` method, as it does for `attributes()`. But there you go :)

Comment: @Robert maybe post it as a suggestion on the groovy jira with the example problem you've got and the current best solution? You never know, it might make it to 1.8.7 :-) you can even do pull requests now groovy is on github

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I have found so far involves falling back on reflection.

As Damo pointed out above, `NodeChild` contains a `Node` property and inside `Node` is the `attributeNamespaces` map I need to get a hold of.

The `Node` class does not expose this property (as it does with `attributes()`), and it only seems to be used inside the `build()` method. Darn.

Having retrieved the node, I therefore call:

```
def attributeNamespacesField = node.getClass().getDeclaredField("attributeNamespaces")
attributeNamespacesField.setAccessible(true)
def attributeNamespacesMap = attributeNamespacesField.get(node)
```

It works, although it doesn't feel so *Groovy*.

Comment: Added an edit to my answer showing a groovier way of accessing `attributeNamespaces`, but I still don't think it's 100% the solution you wanted...